# Leaflet map appears to be missing buildings. What are the options?

Tags: javascript, plugins, leaflet

I was looking at some leaflet maps and they are sooo cool and impressive! The only downside is that it appears that a lot of buildings are missing from the map. Are their third party plugins to overcome that or maybe a way that I can contribute to help fill in those buildings? Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: Hey just to help out anybody else in the future who may have my same frustration. When you compare Leaflet to Google Maps Road Map you will realize there are a lot of buildings that are missing on the Leaflet map because Leaflet only shows what have been outlined on Open Street Map. There is a nice Google Maps plug-in to get around that by Pavel Shramov that shows the tiles of all the buildings that seemed to be missing.http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#services-providers-and-formats

Answer (score 1):

The buildings are part of the tile layers displayed using Leaflet, and not of Leaflet itself. Most of the time, Leaflet maps are using OpenStreetMap tiles, to which you can contribute too.

http://www.openstreetmap.org/

Also, you can have a look at the multiple tile layers available, maybe you'll find something that suits your needs:

http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/keir.clarke/leaflet/leafletlayers.htm